# Why does Spark Streaming application work fine using sbt run but does not on Tomcat (as web application)?

Tags: scala, tomcat, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a Spark application in Scala which grabs records from Kafka every 10 seconds and saves them as files. This is SBT project and I run my app with `sbt run` command. Everything works fine until I deploy my app on Tomcat. I managed to generate WAR file with [this plugin](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/tree/master/) but it looks like my app does not do anything when deployed on Tomcat.
This is my code:

```
object SparkConsumer {
  def main (args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("KafkaReceiver")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))


    val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "group_id",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
    )
    val topics = Array("mytopic")
    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
    )

    stream.map(record => (record.key, record.value)).print

    val arr = new ArrayBuffer[String]();

    val lines = stream.map(record => (record.key, record.value));

    stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>

      if (rdd.count() > 0 ) {
            val date = System.currentTimeMillis()
            rdd.saveAsTextFile ("/tmp/sparkout/mytopic/" + date.toString)
            rdd.foreach { record => println("t=" + record.topic + " m=" + record.toString()) }
      }

      println("Stream had " + rdd.count() + " messages")

      val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
        rdd.foreachPartition { iter =>
        val o: OffsetRange = offsetRanges(TaskContext.get.partitionId)
        println(s"${o.topic} ${o.partition} ${o.fromOffset} ${o.untilOffset}")
        println(o)
      }
    }

    stream.saveAsTextFiles("/tmp/output")


    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

The strange thing is that the app works completely fine when ran via `sbt run` command. It reads the records from Kafka properly and saves them as files in the desired directory. I have no idea what is happening. I tried to enable logging with `log4j` but it doesn't even log anything when on Tomcat. I've been looking for an answer but haven't found the solution.

**To sum up**

My Scala Spark app (which is SBT project) should read records from Kafka and save them as files every 10 seconds. It works when ran via `sbt run` command but it doesn't when deployed on Tomcat.

**Additional info:**

- Scala 2.12
- Tomcat 7
- SBT 0.13.15
- *ask for more*

**Q:** What is the problem?

Comment: I would speculate that there might be libraries missing in the classpath. Have you tied debugging the remote application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** The standalone application `SparkConsumer` behaves properly on Tomcat and so does Tomcat itself.

I'm very surprised to have read the question because your code is not something that I'd expect working **ever** on Tomcat. Sorry.

Tomcat is a servlet container and as such requires servlets in a web application.

Even though you managed to create a WAR and deploy it to Tomcat, you did not "trigger" anything from this web application to start a Spark Streaming application (the code inside `main` method).

The Spark Streaming application does work fine when executed using `sbt run` because that's the goal of `sbt run`, i.e. execute standalone application in a sbt-managed project.

Given you have only one standalone application in your sbt project, `sbt run` has managed to find `SparkConsumer` and execute its `main` entry method. No surprise here.

It however won't work on Tomcat. You'd have to expose the application as a POST or GET endpoint and use a HTTP client (a browser or command-line tool like curl, wget or httpie) to execute it.

Spark does not support Scala 2.12 so...how did you manage to use the Scala version with Spark?! *Impossible!*